# How do I create a database inside command prompt using PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, command-prompt

I am trying to create a 'test' database to see if my input is being accepted but for some reason when I type into the command prompt window I am unable to create the database using SQL commands.

Additionally, I am extremely new to this, and this my first time so I apologize in advance if I did miss anything obvious.

Here is what I am getting:

```
C:\Users\svd\Documents\Github\Test\Covid_Detection_02>CREATE DATABASE new_user
'CREATE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\svd\Documents\Github\Test\Covid_Detection_02>createdb new_user
'createdb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

You can also run commands directly from the command prompt using `psql -c`. From the documentation:

> -c command
> --command=command Specifies that psql is to execute the given command string, command. This option can be repeated and combined in any order
> with the -f option. When either -c or -f is specified, psql does not
> read commands from standard input; instead it terminates after
> processing all the -c and -f options in sequence.
>
> command must be either a command string that is completely parsable by
> the server (i.e., it contains no psql-specific features), or a single
> backslash command. Thus you cannot mix SQL and psql meta-commands
> within a -c option. To achieve that, you could use repeated -c options
> or pipe the string into psql

So, for example:

```
psql -c 'CREATE DATABASE new_user'
```

Documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-psql.html

**PREVIOUS RESPONSE:**

You don't appear to be operating within the Postgres interactive terminal, so the commands are not recognized (since you are in a regular command line session).

Make sure Postgres is installed, then start the Postgres interactive termimal using:

```
psql -U username
```

Where "username" is your username. It will then prompt you for your password. From there, after logging in successfully, you will see something like:

```
postgres=#
```

Once there, then enter the commands you want, such as `CREATE DATABASE new_user`.

More documentation:

- https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/postgresql/log-in-postgresql-database/
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-psql.html

Comment: Thanks for the response but is there a way to use the commands inside the windows command prompt instead of the psql terminal?

Comment: Yes, though it is not as easy. I have updated by answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Your first command would need to be run at a `psql` prompt, or some other SQL client.  You are running it at the OS prompt.

Your second command should be run at the OS prompt, but the your PATH apparently is not set correctly so it can find the program `createdb`.  But if it can't find that program, it probably can't find `psql` either.

You should set your PATH so that Windows can find the programs. How did you install PostgreSQL?  I think the installer usually offers to do this or you, but you have to select the option telling it to.  You can also set up your PATH yourself manually using Windows configuration tools.  Alternatively, you could specify the full patch to the program when you execute it:

```
C:\Users\jjanes> "c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\createdb.exe" -U postgres new_user
```

Comment: I recall the path being set by the installer for PostgreSQL.

`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12`

How do you set the path so that it can find it?

Answer (score -1):

1. install postgreSQL.
2. run in command line:

```
psql -U userName
```

then enter your password when prompted. This will start the interactive terminal

3. run:

```
CREATE DATABASE new_user
```

Check this site: https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/idol/IDOL_12_0/MediaServer/Guides/html/English/Content/Getting_Started/Configure/_TRN_Set_up_PostgreSQL.htm

Comment: Thanks for the reply but do you know of any way to use it inside the windows command prompt?

Comment: In the site that I referenced there is an instruction on how to run it if isn't set in the path by looking psql.exe in the filesystem